# How to specify additional files as prerequisites that would cause ASDF to recompile the program

Tags: common-lisp, asdf

I have written a program that uses read-time evaluation to read strings contained in text files. In this example, the text files are `1.txt` and `2.txt`, both of which contain text that will be read during read-time. The problem: ASDF will not recompile the program when I edit `1.txt` or `2.txt` even though the contents of these files affect the behavior of the program. How do I add these two files as additional "prerequisites" that would cause the program to be recompiled if the files are modified?

This is the program in question:

`myprog.asd`:

```lisp
(defpackage myprog-asd
  (:use :cl :asdf))
(in-package :myprog-asd)

(defsystem "myprog"
  :components ((:file "myprog")))
```

`myprog.lisp`:

```lisp
(in-package :cl-user)

(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (defun read-file-string (path)
    "Returns the contents of the file as a string"
    (with-open-file (stream path :direction :input)
      (let ((str (make-string (file-length stream))))
        (read-sequence str stream)
        str))))

(defun run-main ()
  (princ #.(read-file-string "1.txt"))
  (princ #.(read-file-string "2.txt"))
  nil)
```

Create the `1.txt` and `2.txt`:

```
$ echo 'Hello' > 1.txt
$ echo 'World' > 2.txt
```

Compile and run the program:

```
$ sbcl
* (require "asdf")
* (asdf:load-asd (merge-pathnames "myprog.asd" (uiop:getcwd)))
* (asdf:load-system :myprog)
* (run-main)
Hello
World
NIL
```

If I modify `1.txt` or `2.txt`, the program would not be recompiled, resulting in wrong output for `(run-main)`:

```
$ echo 'Hi!' > 1.txt
$ echo 'Bye!' > 2.txt
$ sbcl
* (require "asdf")
* (asdf:load-asd (merge-pathnames "myprog.asd" (uiop:getcwd)))
* (asdf:load-system :myprog)
* (run-main)
Hello
World
NIL
```

How do I fix this problem? `(asdf:load-system :myprog :force t)` could fix the problem but it recompiles the program even when there are no changes.

(SBCL 2.2.2; ASDF 3.3.5; Ubuntu 20.04)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just include the auxiliary files as additional dependencies, using the `:static-file` directive:

```
(defsystem "myprog"
  :components ((:static-file "1.txt")
               (:static-file "2.txt")
               (:file "myprog" :depends-on ("1.txt" "2.txt"))))
```